# spring 3.1 @Cacheable example

Tags: java, caching, spring-annotations

I am new to spring annotation and i want to create a sample example which shows the use of **@Cacheable annotation** in spring 3.1 does any one have guidance to create this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hope following link may be helpful to you... [A sample application](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/spring-31-cache-abstraction-tutorial.html).

Also have a look on Spring's documentation [for cache abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) and [spring source blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/23/spring-3-1-m1-caching/).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of links to learn from

- [simple-spring-memcached](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached)
- [Cache Abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) Spring 3.2
- [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) Spring 3.2
- [Cache abstraction in Spring 3/](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/cache-abstraction-in-spring-3/)

I did a POC using spring cache, Simple Spring Memcached and Memcache. The svn link of working application code is here

[Simple Spring Memcached – Spring Caching Abstraction and Memcached](http://weblog4j.com/2013/05/31/simple-spring-memcached-spring-caching-abstraction-and-memcached/)